# Advanced Find - combine related entitie with OR

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there any way to create that query?

[image]

I need data from Adress and Contact Adress, normally i can just combine them by `Combine OR` but not in this case.

I guess that i must write new plugin with `PreExecute()` method, get my query, parse data and then manualy get equal address OR there are other way?

Comment: Are you attempting to just create a view, or are you trying to access the data through the SDK?

Comment: Does not matter. I only need to display the data to the user in view. I was interested in the possibility that the system represents for the developer. And found out that the only way to do it - write a plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

- Create Plugin for pre-validation with `Execute()` method and some
  method for data parsing.
- In entity view add some field with `GUID`.
- If plugin found guid in your view, it 'll get fetchxml query for your
  entity and second query entity else 'll show default view.
- Parse data for what you want show for user.
- Register your plugin.
- Profit.

PS I'll add sources in day or two after refactoring and approval from customer.

**Edit:**

First of all - y need create new `GUID` and add string field to view with that guid to view(It is better to hide it from the user).
Create plugin with `RetrieveMultiple` action and `Post` validation(in `Pre` action you may lose your changes)

In plugin: main method
`RetrieveMultiple` which will get context and service from wich you will take query, then you need get fetchXml and check if there are your `GUID`.

```
            string fetchXml = string.Empty;
            var query = context.InputParameters["Query"] as QueryExpression;
            var fetchQuery = context.InputParameters["Query"] as FetchExpression;

                if (query == null)
                {
                    if (fetchQuery == null)
                    {
                    return;
                    }
               fetchXml = fetchQuery.Query;
                }

                // Convert query to a fetch expression for processing and apply filter
                else
                {
                    fetchXml =
                        ((QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse)
                            service.Execute(new QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest {Query = query})).FetchXml;
                }

                if (fetchXml.Contains(OpportunityFilterGuid))
            {
                    ApplyFilter(context, service, query);
                }
            }
```

In your `ApllyFilter` method you need:

1. Get query from user(he can add some new fileds).
2. Delete your field with `GUID`.
3. Execute query.
4. Delete fileds, that can conflict with your `OR` statement.
5. Add `link-entity` to query.
6. Execute query.
7. Add received entities from second query to first.
8. Using LINQ select entities wich are not repeated.

   ```
    collectionOne.Entities.GroupBy(oppId => oppId.Id).Select(opp => opp.First())
   ```
9. Send that data to client.

Answer (score 3):

I am unaware of any way to do the above.

Rather than write a plugin however I would do a report.

Simplest way I can think of is to do your fetchXML without filters like so.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <attribute name="address1_city" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <link-entity name="contact" from="parentcustomerid" to="accountid" alias="ac">
        <attribute name="address1_city" />
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Then toggle visibilty of rows in your report using

```
=Fields!address1_city.Value="Sydney" Or Fields!ac_address1_city.Value="Sydney"
```

Obviously you could replace Sydney with a Parameter

Comment: I need make that for one of entity views. So, as i gues, you give nice idea but not for me. Yes?

Comment: Correct the above will not help you with entity views. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, there is no way to do what you are asking through advanced find.

The example query you put up will only show you Accounts where associated Contacts have the address match (as well as obviously the Account having the address match).  Once you associate another entity in an Advanced Find, you will only see parents with the associated records - there is no ability to do (what is effectively) an outer join.

Your only options are really to build something in Silverlight or HTML and add it as a web-resource - once inside that code you can pretty much display anything you want.  As others have suggested, this is possible in a report.

Comment: Nothing is impossible in programming. There are always Workaround.