# RetrieveMultiple plugin does not display charts

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a plug-in on `Pre` of `RetriveMultiple`.
It works well, but does not display charts.

[image: View and chart]

Have someone met solution for such problem?

Update:
I modified view with my custom `GUID`, if plugin found it, then performs action.

In `PreRetriveMultiple` I pass modified `QueryExpression` to `context.InputParameters["Query"]`.

From this `QueryExpression` deleted my `GUID` and added list of records from link entity with `OR` condition.

Same issue:
[By ZOHAIB UDDIN KHAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974300/chart-generation-is-not-considering-the-retrievemultiple-plugin#comment31211136_16974300)

[His topic on community.dynamics.com](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/107466.aspx) with post by AASHTON that have this issue.

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995575/advanced-find-combine-related-entitie-with-or

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show all of the code, if you are interested in something detailed, I can rewrite it, to show. I've updated the post and added a link to it how it all began.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common issue. You can not remove the charts or dashboards from the query.  There is not a good way to hide those views from the lists.  I wish that I could explain the answer, but I can't... just the way it is.

Hope that it helps you by proving it's not just you! :)

Comment: Oh, I already did that! My plugin doesn't display charts(I don't know how or what I break), but I want pass them back! =)